# Netty ChannelHandler closed when SSL is used

Tags: java, ssl, client, netty, keep-alive

I have a problem using netty in a client/server environment. After setting up the server with

```
bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(); 
workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(); 
try {
    serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(); 
    serverBootstrap.group(bossGroup, workerGroup); 
    serverBootstrap.channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class); 
    serverBootstrap.childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() { 
        @Override
        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel channel) throws Exception {
            channel.pipeline().addLast(new ObjectEncoder(), new ObjectDecoder(Integer.MAX_VALUE, ClassResolvers.cacheDisabled(null)), new UserPacketDecoder(serverRev));
            channel.pipeline().addLast(new LoggingHandler());
        }
    });
    logger.info(language.getProperty("Server.Info.Netty.PortOpened"));
    serverBootstrap.bind(serverPort).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();      
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error(language.getProperty("Server.Error.Netty.Initialize"), e);
}
```

with ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter "UserPacketDecoder":

```
@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object incomingPacket) {
    /* Identify */   
    if(incomingPacket instanceof GetNews){
        logger.info("Incoming -> GetNews");
        GetNewsAnswer outgoingPacket = new GetNewsAnswer();
        ctx.writeAndFlush(outgoingPacket).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
    } 
}


@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable e) {
    logger.error("Error in Netty-Core", e);
    ctx.close();
}
```

The Client connects, sends a request-packet, awaits answer-packet from server and should close the connection by:

```
workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
bootstrap = new Bootstrap(); 
bootstrap.group(workerGroup); 
bootstrap.channel(NioSocketChannel.class); 
bootstrap.handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
    @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel channel)  {                       
        channel.pipeline().addLast(new ObjectEncoder(), new ObjectDecoder(50000000, ClassResolvers.cacheDisabled(null)), new PacketRelay());
        channel.pipeline().addLast(new LoggingHandler());
    }
});  
try {    
    bootstrap.connect(hostIP, hostPort).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync(); 
} catch (Exception e) { 
    logger.error("Error connecting", e);
}   finally {
    workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
}
```

with ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter "PacketRelay":

```
@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    if( ! (outgoingPacket == null)){
        ctx.writeAndFlush(outgoingPacket);
    }
}       
@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object incomingPacket) {
    incomingPacketQueue.add(incomingPacket);
    ctx.close();
}   

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable e) {
    logger.error("Error in Netty-Core", e);
    ctx.close();
}
```

Without encryption everything is working fine! 
Now i enable SSL (self-signed-certs) on serverside with

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", ksPath);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", ksPW);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", tsPath);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", tsPW);

SSLContext ctx = null;
try {
    ctx = SSLContext.getDefault();
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}   

final SSLEngine engine = ctx.createSSLEngine();
engine.setUseClientMode(false);
engine.setNeedClientAuth(false); //tried both -> true and false
```

and

```
channel.pipeline().addLast("sslHandler", new SslHandler(engine));
```

as first element in the pipeline. On the client side pretty similar

```
SSLContext ctx = null;
try {
    ctx = SSLContext.getDefault();
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}   

final SSLEngine engine = ctx.createSSLEngine();
engine.setUseClientMode(true);
```

and

```
channel.pipeline().addLast("sslHandler", new SslHandler(engine));
```

as first element in the pipeline. As you can see i have enabled netty's debugging mode by adding a new LoggingHandler() to pipeline. Also i set

```
InternalLoggerFactory.setDefaultFactory(new Log4JLoggerFactory());
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl"); 
System.setProperty("ssl.debug", "true");
```

for additional logging.

The first request from client is processed like expected, but i see an exception on client-side:

```
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 30, 112, 54, 24, 223, 62, 135, 143, 88, 178, 186, 12 }
***
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 96
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, READ: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 96
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 5, 115, 178, 143, 196, 203, 86, 123, 42, 40, 44, 34 }
***
%% Cached client session: [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384]
2018-02-19 16:45:36 DEBUG SslHandler:1435 - [id: 0x0c2c19e6, L:/127.0.0.1:54629 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:23600] HANDSHAKEN: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
2018-02-19 16:45:36 DEBUG LoggingHandler:147 - [id: 0x0c2c19e6, L:/127.0.0.1:54629 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:23600] USER_EVENT: SslHandshakeCompletionEvent(SUCCESS)
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Application Data, length = 129
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, called closeOutbound()
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, closeOutboundInternal()
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 80
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, called closeOutbound()
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, closeOutboundInternal()
2018-02-19 16:45:36 DEBUG LoggingHandler:147 - [id: 0x0c2c19e6, L:/127.0.0.1:54629 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:23600] USER_EVENT: SslCloseCompletionEvent(java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException)
2018-02-19 16:45:36 DEBUG LoggingHandler:147 - [id: 0x0c2c19e6, L:/127.0.0.1:54629 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:23600] INACTIVE
2018-02-19 16:45:36 DEBUG LoggingHandler:147 - [id: 0x0c2c19e6, L:/127.0.0.1:54629 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:23600] UNREGISTERED
GetNews OK   //<-------------------- Answer from server
2018-02-19 16:45:39 DEBUG PoolThreadCache:262 - Freed 13 thread-local buffer(s) from thread: nioEventLoopGroup-2-1
```

and on the server side

```
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, READ: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 96
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 30, 112, 54, 24, 223, 62, 135, 143, 88, 178, 186, 12 }
***
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 5, 115, 178, 143, 196, 203, 86, 123, 42, 40, 44, 34 }
***
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 96
%% Cached server session: [Session-2, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384]
2018-02-19 16:45:36 DEBUG SslHandler:1435 - [id: 0x6245c2c5, L:/127.0.0.1:23600 - R:/127.0.0.1:54629] HANDSHAKEN: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
2018-02-19 16:45:36 DEBUG LoggingHandler:147 - [id: 0x6245c2c5, L:/127.0.0.1:23600 - R:/127.0.0.1:54629] USER_EVENT: SslHandshakeCompletionEvent(SUCCESS)
2018-02-19 16:45:36 INFO  UserPacketDecoder:865 - IncomingPacket -> GetNews        //<-------------------- Request from client
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, WRITE: TLSv1.1 Application Data, length = 144
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, READ: TLSv1.1 Application Data, length = 112
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, WRITE: TLSv1.1 Application Data, length = 144
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, READ: TLSv1.1 Application Data, length = 112
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, WRITE: TLSv1.1 Application Data, length = 176
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, READ: TLSv1.1 Application Data, length = 160
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, WRITE: TLSv1.1 Application Data, length = 96
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, READ: TLSv1.1 Application Data, length = 992
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, WRITE: TLSv1.1 Application Data, length = 96
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, READ: TLSv1.1 Application Data, length = 1136
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, WRITE: TLSv1.1 Application Data, length = 112
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, READ: TLSv1.1 Application Data, length = 432
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, WRITE: TLSv1.1 Application Data, length = 80
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, READ: TLSv1.1 Application Data, length = 64
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, WRITE: TLSv1.1 Application Data, length = 96
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, READ: TLSv1.1 Application Data, length = 64
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, WRITE: TLSv1.1 Application Data, length = 80
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, READ: TLSv1.1 Application Data, length = 128
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Application Data, length = 122
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 80
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, close_notify
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, closeInboundInternal()
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, closeOutboundInternal()
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 80
2018-02-19 16:45:36 DEBUG LoggingHandler:147 - [id: 0x6245c2c5, L:/127.0.0.1:23600 - R:/127.0.0.1:54629] USER_EVENT: SslCloseCompletionEvent(SUCCESS)
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, called closeOutbound()
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, closeOutboundInternal()
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, called closeInbound()
nioEventLoopGroup-3-1, closeInboundInternal()
2018-02-19 16:45:36 DEBUG LoggingHandler:147 - [id: 0x6245c2c5, L:/127.0.0.1:23600 ! R:/127.0.0.1:54629] INACTIVE
2018-02-19 16:45:36 DEBUG LoggingHandler:147 - [id: 0x6245c2c5, L:/127.0.0.1:23600 ! R:/127.0.0.1:54629] UNREGISTERED
```

From now on every connection attempt by a client is registered by the SSLHandler on server, but no Object is transmitted. Client-Output:

```
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 203
2018-02-19 16:55:39 DEBUG Recycler:96 - -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread: 32768
2018-02-19 16:55:39 DEBUG Recycler:97 - -Dio.netty.recycler.maxSharedCapacityFactor: 2
2018-02-19 16:55:39 DEBUG Recycler:98 - -Dio.netty.recycler.linkCapacity: 16
2018-02-19 16:55:39 DEBUG Recycler:99 - -Dio.netty.recycler.ratio: 8
2018-02-19 16:55:39 DEBUG AbstractByteBuf:52 - -Dio.netty.buffer.bytebuf.checkAccessible: true
2018-02-19 16:55:39 DEBUG ResourceLeakDetectorFactory:202 - Loaded default ResourceLeakDetector: io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector@13e73780
2018-02-19 16:55:49 DEBUG LoggingHandler:147 - [id: 0x25b3173b, L:/127.0.0.1:55853 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:23600] USER_EVENT: SslHandshakeCompletionEvent(javax.net.ssl.SSLException: handshake timed out)
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, called closeOutbound()
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, closeOutboundInternal()
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, called closeInbound()
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, fatal error: 80: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = internal_error
nioEventLoopGroup-2-1, Exception sending alert: java.io.IOException: writer side was already closed.
2018-02-19 16:55:49 DEBUG LoggingHandler:147 - [id: 0x25b3173b, L:/127.0.0.1:55853 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:23600] USER_EVENT: SslCloseCompletionEvent(java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException)
2018-02-19 16:55:49 DEBUG LoggingHandler:147 - [id: 0x25b3173b, L:/127.0.0.1:55853 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:23600] INACTIVE
2018-02-19 16:55:49 DEBUG LoggingHandler:147 - [id: 0x25b3173b, L:/127.0.0.1:55853 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:23600] UNREGISTERED
2018-02-19 16:55:51 DEBUG PoolThreadCache:262 - Freed 4 thread-local buffer(s) from thread: nioEventLoopGroup-2-1
```

I can't find the answer... Thanks in advise

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a [connection reuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) when the client should close properly, and open a new one. There are 2 proofs of that : the fact it's working for the 1st request only, and the [close_notify](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.2.1) message sent by the client (and after it, the one sent by the server). After this 1st succeeded transaction, the log shows an SSL handshake timeout which is a normal phenomenon on an SSL connection which is supposed to be closed already.

I don't have enough knowledge for now about netty to give the exact solution, but understanding the cause should help you a lot. In this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404917/how-to-use-netty-to-handle-http-keep-alive-connections) they're giving a way to disable the HTTP Keep-Alive, which is precisely what we want to achieve, by setting the header to Close value. They're fighting against the opposite problem but maybe give us the solution.

Comment: Thanks to Eugéne for additional explanation of the SSL process. If the connection is already closed by client, why should disable Keep-Alive help in this situation? In your referenced thread a HttpResponse is used, which Header was set to Close value. How can this be transcribed to my example which is not using HttpResponse?

Comment: The network connection is still opened but you cannot use it anymore because the client sent a TLS close_notify alert. You need to close the network connection, and I'm thinking that disabling the Keep-Alive header value could be the solution. There must be a way to achieve this if you're not using HttpResponse, but I'm no netty expert, I just can read the doc for this.

Comment: You wrote "The Client connects, sends a request-packet, awaits answer-packet from server and closes the connection by:" . I have doubts that this is closing anything. A network capture would show if yes or not, it is closing. Or you can monitor the connections with netstat -an and filter on the server port

Comment: Thanks Eugéne... I tried to deactivate keep-alive behavior by setting serverBootstrap.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, false) on server side. It results a warning -> ServerBootstrap:460 - Unknown channel option 'SO_KEEPALIVE' for channel '[id: 0xf4ed9bbf]'. Also i changed ctx.writeAndFlush(outgoingPacket).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE); in UserPacketDecoder. It has no effect.

Comment: Is anyone able to explain how i could close down the connection correctly? If there's another approach to solve this problem, please let me know.

Comment: @knoop : the SO_KEEPALIVE is a TCP setting, not at all the HTTP keep-alive which maintains connections opened. The names look similar and bring some people in mistake. Anyway I believe it's a big step in understanding the problem after one week turning round.

Comment: maybe a stupid idea, but in exceptionCaught() is it necessary to call ctx.close() too ?

Comment: it's not called there, ctx.close() is called once in channelRead() after getting answer object.

Comment: Have a look at the Discard Server example ( http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html ), their exceptionCaught() is calling ctx.close() as I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks...added, but no change

Comment: I can't go further since I'm not into netty, sorry, and I can't even offer a bounty as this feature is not available for me on this question. It is frustrating since I believe we're next to the solution. I just can suggest reading examples (maybe https://findusages.com/search/io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler/SslHandler$1 ?)

Comment: Where is the evidence that the same TCP connection is being reused?

Comment: @EJP I concluded this is a reuse problem because on the 1st request there is the close_notify, while on the 2nd parts of the handshake are missing. I can be wrong : the client port is 54629on the first, 55853 on the second. If this comes from the very same test, it shows differents connections. I investigated again each log line : ResourceLeakDetectorFactory could be linked to a memory leakage, and there are people complaining about similar things with ElasticSearch (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound => memory leakage in the caller code).

Comment: @EugèneAdell You need to look up SSL session resumption. It can occur across separate TCP connections.